# check XSLT Element and input space if element is missing

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, element, xslt-3.0

I am transforming an incoming XML where some elements won’t show up. if element has no data then that particular element won’t show up. In below sample example I am having total 4 XML report groups where for each and every group expected tags are EmployeeId,first_name,last_name,job_code,active Total  5 tags. However for few groups some or other element will be missing where I need to put space. For report group 1 and 3 all elements are present and report entry 2 last_name is missing and for report entry 4 both active and first_name are missing

When I am writing into O/P I wants to make sure to input a space if any element is missing else it will create data issues , Column heading and column data mismatch issues

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<master>
<report_group>
    <employeeid>05121</employeeid>
    <first_name>John</first_name>
    <last_name>Blad</last_name>
    <job_code>0001</job_code>
   <active>Y</active>
</report_group>
<report_group>
    <employeeid>05671</employeeid>
    <first_name>Cris</first_name>
    <job_code>0002</job_code>
    <active>N</active>     
</report_group>
<report_group>
    <employeeid>05432</employeeid>
    <first_name>Vel</first_name>
    <last_name>Harris</last_name>
    <job_code>0004</job_code>
    <active>Y</active>
</report_group>
<report_group>
    <employeeid>05672</employeeid>
    <last_name>vens</last_name>
    <job_code>789</job_code>
</report_group>
```

Expected output is in CSV and like below

```
id,fname,lname,jbcode,active
05121,John,Blad,0001,Y
05671,Cris, ,0002,N
05432,Vel,Harris,0004,Y
05672, ,vens,789,
```

Any body faced this type of issue? Any body has any idea how to deal with this type of situation ?

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, either feed the child element selection to a function that outputs the space if the selection is an empty sequence:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:space-if-empty" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="item()?"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="if (empty($input)) then ' ' else string($input)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="report_group">
      <xsl:value-of select="mf:space-if-empty(employeeid), mf:space-if-empty(first_name), mf:space-if-empty(last_name), mf:space-if-empty(job_code), mf:space-if-empty(active)" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTm is an online sample.

Or run the input through a mode that adds the missing elements with a space:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:mode name="add-dummy-elements" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="report_group" mode="add-dummy-elements">
      <xsl:copy>
          <employeeid>{mf:space-if-empty(employeeid)}</employeeid>
          <first_name>{mf:space-if-empty(first_name)}</first_name>
          <last_name>{mf:space-if-empty(last_name)}</last_name>
          <job_code>{mf:space-if-empty(job_code)}</job_code>
          <active>{mf:space-if-empty(active)}</active>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="mf:space-if-empty" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="item()?"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="if (empty($input)) then ' ' else string($input)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:variable name="input-with-dummies-added">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-dummy-elements"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>id,fname,lname,jbcode,active&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$input-with-dummies-added/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="report_group">
      <xsl:value-of select="employeeid, first_name, last_name, job_code, active" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTm/1 shows that.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I followed first method and it's really help full